# Progress Dialog over partial screen

Tags: android, android-fragments, progressdialog

I have a fragment with three tabs. On one of the tabs I have a dialog that spins when a background sync going on. But I need to be able to continue work on other parts when the background sync is going on.

I am currently use `dialog.setCancelable(false)` to go out of the dialog so that I can use the rest of the app. But that gives me an emoty screen on the fragment where the sync is going on.

Is there any way to have the dialog only overlay over part of the screen(only the fragment where the sync is going on)?. In other words a dialog that does not take the entire screen so that I can move to the other tabs without cancelling the dialog?

Implementation of dialog in java code:

```
    dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
    dialog.setCancelable(true);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_progress_bar);
    dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);
```

dialog.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/dialogProgressBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Why don't you use `progressBar` straightaway in the fragmnet's xml rather than showing it in a `Dialog` ?

Comment: yeah it works. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No,** you can't achieve this behavior with `Dialog`.

**#.** As you are using `Fragment` and want to show `progress` of syncing, so I think you can add a `ProgressBar` in your Fragment `layout` XML instead of using `Dialog` and show/hide `ProgressBar` as per `sync` state.

**STATE:**

1. when sync is `going on`, show `ProgressBar` only and hide others `Views` .
2. when sync `completed`, hide `ProgressBar` and show others `Views` as per your needs.

**#.** You can also use [SwipeRefreshLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.html) in your Fragment `layout` XML to show that the progress is going on. It will `show` a circular `ProgressBar` when `sync` is going on and `hide` automatically when `sync` complete.

Here is a good tutorial: [Android Swipe Down to Refresh ListView Tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/05/android-swipe-down-to-refresh-listview-tutorial/)

Hope this will help~